# What is $VIM and where do I find it?

Tags: vim

Likewise, how do I find `$VIMRUNTIME`?

I installed vim using `yum install vim-X11 vim-common vim-enhanced vim-minimal` on CentOS 6.3

Comment: Inside vim, run the commands `:echo $VIM`  and `:echo $VIMRUNTIME`

Comment: 1. Why not simply `$ yum install vim-X11`? 2. Why do you care? You are not supposed to do anything in `$VIM` or `$VIMRUNTIME` anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find `$VIM` and `$VIMRUNTIME`, you can run

```
:echo $VIM
:echo $VIMRUNTIME
```

and to answer what is $VIM, you can run

```
:h $VIM
```

> The environment variable "$VIM" is used to locate various user files for Vim, such as the user startup script ".vimrc".  This depends on the system, see startup.

Inorder to set these environment variables, use

```
:let $VIM = "/path/to/directory"
:let $VIMRUNTIME = "/path/to/directory"
```

You can also find `$VIM` and `$VIMRUNTIME` from console or if you want it in a shell script

```
vim -e -T dumb --cmd 'exe "set t_cm=\<C-M>"|echo $VIMRUNTIME|quit' | tr -d '\015'
vim -e -T dumb --cmd 'exe "set t_cm=\<C-M>"|echo $VIM|quit' | tr -d '\015'
```

Answer (score 2):

These are the environment variables set by `vim` when you are inside `vim` and spawn a shell from within `vim`. You won't find them set in any other case.

For example, if you run `:!bash` from `vim`, then the spawned shell will have both these environment variables set.

You should run `:help $VIM` to know more about both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Those are built into vim. Try this in vim:

```
:echo $VIM
:echo $VIMRUNTIME
```